# pset4 cs50 recover.c guidance

Tags: c, file, io, recover, cs50

I could use some help for this problem set from cs50. Whenever my code hits the while loop, the fread function returns 0. I can't seem to understand why this happens. Even before I ran into this problem my code wasn't working as I desired so if there are any additional tips It would be really helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//PROTOTYPES 
bool check(uint8_t block[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r"); //open up the card.raw file for reading

    if(inptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Could not open the card data.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* outptr;

    int jpegCount = 0;
    bool foundFirstJpg = false;// flag to denote wheather the first jpg has been found

    char str[10]; //to hold the jpg name
    sprintf(str, "%i.jpg", jpegCount); //puts the image name in str
    jpegCount ++;
    outptr = fopen(str, "w"); //Create a new jpeg for each image

    uint8_t block[512]; // a tempory block to hold 512 bytes of info 

    while(fread(block, sizeof(block), 1, inptr) == 1) //read 512 bytes of info at a time from the inptr)
    {
        printf("hello\n");
        if(check(block)) //if I have found a jpg
        {
            if(foundFirstJpg) //if its not my first jpg
            {
                fclose(outptr); //close the previous jpg file
                sprintf(str, "%i.jpg", jpegCount); //puts the image name in str
                outptr = fopen(str, "w"); //Create a new jpeg for each image
                jpegCount ++;
                fwrite(block, sizeof(block), 1, outptr); //write the block to the image file 
            }
            else
            {
                fwrite(block, sizeof(block), 1, outptr); //write first block to the image file 
                foundFirstJpg = true; 
            }
        }
        else //if this is not a jpg
        {
            if(foundFirstJpg) //check if we have found our first jpg
            {
                 fwrite(block, sizeof(block), 1, outptr); //write 512 bytes to the current image file
            }
        }
    } 
    if (outptr)
    {
         fclose(outptr);
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    return 0;
}

//function to check if this is the start or end of a jpg
bool check(uint8_t block[])
{
    bool isJpg = true; //boolean value to be returned
    if (block[0] != 0xff || block[1] != 0xd8 || block[2] != 0xff) //checks if the first 3 bytes are those that represent a jpg
    {
        isJpg = false;
    }
    if (block[3] < 0xe0 || block[3] > 0xef) //checks if the fourth byte also represents a jpg
    {
        isJpg = false;
    }
    return isJpg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud open these files in binary mode:

```
FILE *inptr = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
...
outptr = fopen(str, "wb");
```

If `card.raw` has less than 512 bytes, `fread` will return `0`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't resolve my problem. Thank you for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Also when I run 'xxd -l 2400 card.raw' to try and read some bytes from card.raw, to see if can get anything at all. Nothing shows up. My command line just moves to the next line down.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is happening without a copy of the `card.raw` file.

Comment: I need to preface this with an apology. I'm sorry for wasting your time when you were trying to help me. I have had a sneaking suspicion that there was a problem with card.raw. It turns out it was empty, 0 bytes. I must have emptied it somehow in an earlier rendition of my program. After redownloading it my program ran fine. I took me so long as I am unfamiliar with the ide that I am working with and so was having trouble investigating the file. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I guess my hint was right on the dot: *If card.raw has less than 512 bytes, fread will return 0.*.